# Dominated Convergence Theorem properties

Tags: probability, convergence

The original definition for Dominated Convergence Theorem is that $X_n\xrightarrow { a.s.}X$ and $|X_n|\le Y \ \ \ \ \forall n\implies E(X_n)\to E(X)$.

However if we replace *almost sure* conevergence with convergence *in probability*, then also the theorem holds.

So I want to know what is the most general version of DCT? In particular, in what other types of convergences does the theorem work? What are the other conditions that we can relax and still have DCT holding?

Comment: The answer is yes - see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206851/generalisation-of-dominated-convergence-theorem

Comment: @Math1000 To which question?